# Difference between two specified times with snapshots of data at unknown times

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to be able to get the change between two rows in a table that are closest to the dates provided. The rows in the table store the data at that specific time, not the delta from the previous snapshot.

I want to be able to give a query two dates that are likely not to be contained within the table, and to get a difference of the count of the two closest time periods within that date range.

Here's a simple example of a table:

```
objectID    snapshotTime            dataCount
1           2013-01-01 13:00:00     40
1           2013-01-02 18:00:00     51
1           2013-01-02 19:00:00     59
1           2013-01-03 01:00:00     70
1           2013-01-04 14:00:00     82
1           2013-01-05 17:00:00     99
1           2013-01-06 20:00:00     107
```

Given the dates `2013-01-01 20:00:00` and `2013-01-06 12:00:00`, the query should return 48 (99-51).

How could I write such a query that would run efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Try two queries where each uses a WHERE to keep time under its given constraint, and use ASC to make sure you get the next record.  If you want, use LIMIT 1, but doesn't make a difference.  Then use PHP to grab each record and subtract the difference.